# equivalent HTTP queries get different responses

Tags: http, telnet, http-method, http-1.0

`GET http://d9.c4.b1.a0.top.list.ru/ HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: d9.c4.b1.a0.top.list.ru\r\n\r\n`

response:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Server: wz/1.5
Date: Sat, 17 Nov 2012 19:00:20 GMT
Cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
```

---

`GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: d9.c4.b1.a0.top.list.ru\r\n\r\n`

response:

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: wz/1.5
Date: Sat, 17 Nov 2012 19:06:27 GMT
Location: http://top.mail.ru/
Cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
```

What is difference between these queries?

P.S. Queries were made using `telnet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [HTTP 1.0 specification on the *Request-URI*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#Request-URI):

> The *absoluteURI* form is only allowed when the request is being made to a proxy.

So it seems that the server you send this request to is not a proxy but probably the specified server itself.

Using the absolute URI in the request line in a request sent to the specified server is only [valid in HTTP 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1.2):

> To allow for transition to *absoluteURIs* in all requests in future
> versions of HTTP, all HTTP/1.1 servers MUST accept the *absoluteURI*
> form in requests, even though HTTP/1.1 clients will only generate
> them in requests to proxies.